# Stock inventory by attributes set

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problem with storing data from each attributes set, im using eav model, below is my database structure

```
products
--------
id
name

product_attributes
----------
id
name

product_attribute_values
------------------
id
product_id
attribute_id
value
```

Now my problem is how to store data for each attributes set for example:

I sell t-shirt, the t-shirt varies is size and color.

The t-shirt comes in 2 colors(white and black) and 3 sizes(s,m,l)

How should i store data fro sets like this..

```
white,s = 10unit
white,m = 2unit
white,l = 5unit
black,s = 10unit
black,m = 2unit
black,l = 5unit
```

Ant it not only used for t-shirt, it can also be used for other products like shoes which only have one attributes(size)

And help is much apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**Products**
id name
1  t-shirt

**product_attributes**
id product_id  name values
1 1 size l
2 1 size m
3 1 size s
4 1 color white
5 1 color black

**Stock**
stock_id, Product_id Product_Attr_id1 Product_Attr_id2 Product_Attr_id3 Product_Attr_id4 Product_Attr_id5 Quantity

 1 1 4 3 10
 2 1 4 2 2
 3 1 4 1 5   
 4 1 5 3 10
 5 1 5 2 2
 6 1 5 1 5 

**product_attribute_values**
id product_id attribute_id value
1 1 1 s
2 1 1 m
3 1 1 l
4 1 2 white
5 1 2 black
```

Comment: HI, thanks for answering, this part i already solved, my problem is how to track inventory by attributes sets. for example ; size s, white color have 10 unit.. how to store this in database? Thanks

Comment: for this you need to change the db structure.With your existing db strusture its not possible

Comment: how could i do that? should i create another table to store the data? What i tried was to put the attributes set in array and serialize it then store in database, is that a good way to do?

Comment: try the updated structure. Here I have created a table stock assuming any product can have max 5 combinations of attributes.If more you can add more columns.

Comment: thanks man, that really clears up my problem, but by this way its limited to 5 combination of attributes ? right?

Comment: nope if you have more you can just add more columns to the stock table

Comment: hmm.. ok, if i want to query the stock table, how should i handle the null columns? now it have 5 columns for attributes but only two is used.. thanks

Comment: see when you query stock table you will know for which product you are quwerying and then you will know how many attributes that product has.based on this you query stock table

Comment: select count(distinct name) from product_attributes where product_id=1. Now you will get count as 2. So it means you have to query 2 columns